# Kohana Route to index action

Tags: indexing, action, kohana, routes

I have a problem.

I have code:

```
Route::set('user', '(<controller>(/<id>))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'user',

    'id' => '\d+',
));
```

And mydomain.com/user/1 don't work..

Error:

> The requested URL user/1 was not found on this server.

But when I set the dot between controller and id (or something else):

```
    Route::set('user', '(<controller>.abc(/<id>))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'user',
    'id' => '\d+',
));
```

The mydomain.com/user.abc/1 work.

Why? :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check if the `id` is numeric, right? Then putting it like this in defaults is not the wright way, as you can read in the [3.3 documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing#regex)

```
Route::set('user', '(<controller>(/<id>))',
    array(
        'id' => '\d+',
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action' => 'index',
    ));
```

Also it is important where you define that route if you have more than just one. You **have to provide an action** ([doc](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing#default-values)) either in the route or as default